# Cannot scrape specific content from site - BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am having hard luck scraping this link via Python 3, BeautifulSoup 4

http://www.radisson.com/lansing-hotel-mi-48933/lansing/hotel/dining

I only want to get this section.

```
When you are in ...

Capitol City Grille
This downtown Lansing restaurant offers ...

Capitol City Grille Lounge
For a glass of wine or a ...

Room Service
If you prefer ...
```

I have this code

```
 for rest in dining_page_soup.select("div.copy_left p strong"):

      if rest.next_sibling is not None:
         if rest.next_sibling.next_sibling is not None:
               title = rest.text
               desc = rest.next_sibling.next_sibling
               print ("Title:  "+title)
               print (desc)
```

But it gives me `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

on `desc = rest.next_sibling.next_sibling` even I have an `if` statement to check whether it is `None` or not.

Comment: try using `if not rest.next_sibling is None` and `if not rest.next_sibling.next_sibling is None` instead of above two if statements and see if you get some useful hint?

Comment: could u post it as answer

Comment: Sorry the community here would downvote here for posting any answer I am not sure about , so .. simply replace the two if conditions after the `for rest in dining_page_soup.select("div.copy_left p strong"):` by the if conditions in the above comment in the same order

Comment: Still have the same error

Comment: Try moving `title = rest.text` line below the `desc = rest.next_sibling.next_sibling` line ?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a very simple solution

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r  = requests.get("http://www.radisson.com/lansing-hotel-mi-48933/lansing/hotel/dining")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for found_text in soup.select('div.copy_left'):
    print found_text.text
```

**UPDATE**

According to an improvement of the question, here it is a solution using RE.
A specific workaround have to be made for the 1st paragraph "When you..." since it does not respect the structure of other paragraphs.

```
for tag in soup.find_all(re.compile("^strong")):

    title = tag.text
    desc = tag.next_sibling.next_sibling
    print ("Title:  "+title)
    print (desc)
```

**Output**

> Title: Capitol City Grille
>
> This downtown Lansing restaurant offers delicious, contemporary
>   American cuisine in an upscale yet relaxed environment. You can enjoy
>   dishes that range from fluffy pancakes to juicy filet mignon steaks.
>   Breakfast and lunch buffets are available, as well as an à la carte
>   menu.
>
> Title: Capitol City Grille Lounge
>
> For a glass of wine or a hand-crafted cocktail and great conversation,
>   spend an afternoon or evening at Capitol City Grille Lounge with
>   friends or colleagues.
>
> Title: Room Service
>
> If you prefer to dine in the comfort of your own room, order from the
>   room service menu.
>
> Title: Menus
>
> Breakfast Menu
>
> Title: Capitol City Grille Hours
>
> Breakfast, 6:30-11 a.m.
>
> Title: Capitol City Grille Lounge Hours
>
> Mon-Thu, 11 a.m.-11 p.m.
>
> Title: Room Service Hours
>
> Daily, 6:30 a.m.-2 p.m. and 5-10 p.m.

Comment: i don t want scrape it at once...I want to get Title and Description separately so I can store that into DB later

Comment: I downvoted you and read my comment ... THere is no use to scrape that as you answered

Comment: @Umair may be you need to improve your question instead of down voting. Since you were asking for: "I only want to get this section." You can add the paragraph regarding scrape title and description separately so I can store into DB later...

Comment: You can see in my question that I am storing Title and Desc in separate variables .... There is a reason for that

Comment: @Umair Another approach using Re

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70003/discussion-between-aberna-and-umair).

Comment: thanks for putting on effort for me ... but I dont want Menu section or the rest of the things as I stated in my question already

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using xpath, this should work

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = "http://www.radisson.com/lansing-hotel-mi-48933/lansing/hotel/dining"
page = requests.get(url).text
tree = html.fromstring(page)

xp_t = "//*[@class='copy_left']/descendant-or-self::node()/strong[not(following-sibling::a)]/text()"
xp_d = "//*[@class='copy_left']/descendant-or-self::node()/strong[not(following-sibling::a)]/../text()[not(following-sibling::strong)]"

titles = tree.xpath(xp_t)
descriptions = tree.xpath(xp_d)  # still contains garbage like '\r\n'
descriptions = [d.strip() for d in descriptions if d.strip()]

for t, d in zip(titles, descriptions):
    print("{title}: {description}".format(title=t, description=d))
```

Here descriptions contains 3 elements: "This downtown...", "For a glass...", "If you prefer...".

If you need also "When you are in the mood...", replace with this:

```
xp_d = "//*[@class='copy_left']/descendant-or-self::node()/strong[not(following-sibling::a)]/../text()"
```